# Roots of equation in C

Tags: c, calculator, quadratic

I am relatively new to C, and am trying to improve myself in it. I made a calculator and added the quadratic equation solver to it, cause i know the formula of finding the roots. But i am faced with two problems.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <maths.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

main(){
        float A1, A2, A, B, C, ans, Z;
        printf("Welcome to Quadratic Equation solver. Enter the coefficient of X^2, followed by\nthe coefficient of X, followed by the integer value.\n\nEnter values: ");
        scanf("%f%f%f", &A, &B, &C);
        CheckF = (B * B - 4 * A * C);
        if (CheckF < 0) {
          system("COLOR B4");
          printf("This calculator HeX, currently cannot handle complex numbers.\nPlease pardon my developer. I will now redirect you to the main menu.\n");
          system("pause");
          system("cls");
          system("COLOR F1");
          goto Start;
        } else if (CheckF >= 0) {
            Z  = pow(CheckF, 1/2);
            A1 = (-B + Z)/(A+A);
            A2 = (-B - Z)/(A+A);
          if (A1 == A2) {
            ans = A1;
            printf("\nRoot of equation is %f (Repeated root)\n", ans);
            Sleep(250);
          } else if (A1 != A2) {
            printf("Roots of equation are %f and %f \n", A1, A2);
            Sleep(250);
          }
        }
      }
```

Problem 1:
When i run the code and input `3 32 2`, mathematically the output should be `Roots of equation are -0.06287 and -10.6038`, that i double checked with my sharp calculator. However, the output that i got was was off: `Roots of equation are -5.166667 and -5.500000` i am totally unsure why is it not computing the correct roots of the equation.

Problem 2:
Some roots do not have the `coefficient of X^2`, for example (2X + 2), which can be solved to get repeated roots of -2, (6X - 3), which gives us that x is 0.5 repeated. However, according to the quadratic equation, which is divided by 2A, will never work, as it is divided by 0. What is the possible way out of this situation? Is it to check if A = 0 then do something else? Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: For problem 2, any equation without an x^2 term is not quadratic. It's just a line and is easy to solve.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore So, are we supposed to add a if condition to check if A != 0? then if its 0, then ans = -C/B, else if it is not == 0, continue to the quadratic equation right?

Comment: No it's *not quadratic*. You can't solve linear equations with it. Linear equations are only 2 terms with a single term with a variable. It should be easy to solve with simple algebra.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Oh, Ok i will try it. But what about the first problem? Or do you need the full code to run it?

Comment: Create a minimal reproducible example. Your current example *seems* mostly fine. Just be sure to define anything shown in your example that we don't know of.

Comment: Needs a [mcve], yes, but this line `Z  = pow(CheckF, 1/2);` is probably to blame.

Comment: Edited. Now can execute? the line `Z  = pow(CheckF, 1/2);` is just as a pecaution that i did. it can be combined with the `A1 = (-B + Z)/(A+A);`

Comment: If you want to compute a square root, use `sqrt()`, not `pow()`. (Well, `sqrtf()` since you're using floats)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Oh, thanks it worked now. But isnt 1/2 same as 0.5 in terms of values?

Comment: @UnfreeHeX No. In C, `1/2` is an `int` divided by an `int`.  `int` division discards the fractional portion of the mathematical quotient.  `1/2` is `0`.

Comment: `main()` is not standard conforming, since decades. `goto Start;` Where is `Start`?

Comment: @Bob__   The above portion of code is a part of a larger code that has all the other functions. As the problem is with this part, i just cropped and pasted this part only.

Comment: Link to the whole code: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/245679/complex-calculator-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**integer division**

`pow(CheckF, 1/2)` is 1.0 as 1/2 is integer division with a quotient of 0.

```
// Z  = pow(CheckF, 1/2);
Z  = pow(CheckF, 1.0/2.0);
// or better
Z  = sqrt(CheckF);
// Even better when working with `float`.
// Use `float sqrtf(float)` instead of `double sqrt(double)`.
Z  = sqrtf(CheckF);
```

Best - re-write using `double` instead of `float`.  Scant reason for using `float` here.  `double` is the C goto floating point type.

**Other issue**

```
//#include <maths.h>
#include <math.h>

// main() {
int main(void) {

// CheckF = (B * B - 4 * A * C);
float CheckF = (B * B - 4 * A * C);

// goto Start;
```

**Use an auto formater**

Comment: `powf()` and `sqrtf()` are better yet since OP is using floats instead of doubles.

Comment: @Shawn Good advice with `float` types.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Is there any way to handle root of -negative numbers? for the imaginary roots that may occur. Above, i just said that this calculator cannot handle imaginary numbers, but is there any way? i saw some ways of having printf("%fi", ans); but still cannot work

Comment: @UnfreeHeX `complex double d = csqrt(CheckF)` is one direct approach.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Oh. I think my compiler has no `complex.h` header file that comes with it. I looked for its source code, but it includes other files such as `bits/maths.def` and something like that, which i cannot find too. Nevermind. i will just keep it as error. Thank you. Have a wonderful day sir.

Answer (score 1):

I see some problems with the code. First, I suggest you to use double instead of float. They offer much better precision and an ideal calculator needs precision. Secondly, you do:

```
Z  = pow(CheckF, 1/2);
```

You should use sqrt(CheckF) since there is a dedicated function in C for square roots! The following works for me so if you fix the above two problems, your code will probably work.

```
int main() {
    double A1, A2, A, B, C, ans, Z;
    printf("Welcome to Quadratic Equation solver. Enter the coefficient of X^2, followed by\nthe coefficient of X, followed by the integer value.\n\nEnter values: ");
    A = 3;
    B = 32;
    C = 2;
    double CheckF = (B * B - 4 * A * C);
    if (CheckF >= 0) {
        Z  = sqrt(CheckF);
        A1 = (-B + Z) / (A + A);
        A2 = (-B - Z) / (A + A);
        if (A1 == A2) {
            ans = A1;
            printf("\nRoot of equation is %f (Repeated root)\n", ans);
        } else if (A1 != A2) {
            printf("Roots of equation are %f and %f \n", A1, A2);
        }
    }
}
```